# extracting all the (Dutch) city names after zip code with regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have a data frame column with the following syntax:

```
[Jon Doe_Sesamstreet 10_2805JD GOUDA, DENNIS PEPERSTRAATE_Regentesseplantsoen 56_2855CJ Cappele aan de Ijsel]
```

The city ("GOUDA" and "Cappele aan de Ijsel") always comes after the zip code ("2805JD" and "2855 CJ"). I tried using regex, where it looks right after the zip code: "NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER LETTER LETTER" and before "," or "]". However, I am fairly new to regex and was wondering if there is someone that can get me started or has an answer to my question.

Here some extra test cases:

```
[A. Smith_Broekstraat 99-A_4032JZ MAASBRACHT, A. GOEDBLOED 72_9332KL MAASBRACHT]

[T. Loyal_Da Smeet 6_3381AZ Laag Zuthm, T. Oppers</strong>ACSI (Ton)_Loyal 99_6688DR Andelst-Jon Verkade_Nederland]
```

Thanks

Comment: offtop - is gouda a city? i always thought it is just a cheese variety :p

Comment: @marmeladze hahaha yes it’s a city. The cheese ur talking about comes from this city. Not exactly from this city but this city is famous for introducing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a complete regex for german zip code but it works with your sample:

Input data:

```
>>> df
                                             Address
0  [Jon Doe_Sesamstreet 10_2805JD GOUDA, DENNIS P...
1  [A. Smith_Broekstraat 99-A_4032JZ MAASBRACHT, ...
2  [T. Loyal_Da Smeet 6_3381AZ Laag Zuthm, T. Opp...
```

```
df['Cities'] = df['Address'].str.findall(r'[1-9][0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}\s+([^,\]]+)')
```

Output result:

```
>>> df['Cities']
0                  [GOUDA, Cappele aan de Ijsel]
1                       [MAASBRACHT, MAASBRACHT]
2    [Laag Zuthm, Andelst-Jon Verkade_Nederland]
Name: Cities, dtype: object

# OR

>>> df['Cities'].explode()
0                            GOUDA
0             Cappele aan de Ijsel
1                       MAASBRACHT
1                       MAASBRACHT
2                       Laag Zuthm
2    Andelst-Jon Verkade_Nederland
Name: Cities, dtype: object

# OR

>>> df['Cities'].explode().tolist()
['GOUDA',
 'Cappele aan de Ijsel',
 'MAASBRACHT',
 'MAASBRACHT',
 'Laag Zuthm',
 'Andelst-Jon Verkade_Nederland']
```

Comment: Nice! This works! Could you please also give me the regex for the zip code? I cant find one on the internet for Python. Only other languages

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?<=\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2} )[^,\]]+`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tIVYNc/1)

Code:

```
import re

text = """
[Jon Doe_Sesamstreet 10_2805JD GOUDA, DENNIS PEPERSTRAATE_Regentesseplantsoen 56_2855CJ Cappele aan de Ijsel]

[A. Smith_Broekstraat 99-A_4032JZ MAASBRACHT, A. GOEDBLOED 72_9332KL MAASBRACHT]

[T. Loyal_Da Smeet 6_3381AZ Laag Zuthm, T. Oppers</strong>ACSI (Ton)_Loyal 99_6688DR Andelst-Jon Verkade_Nederland]
"""
pattern = "(?<=\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2} )[^,\]]+"
print(re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Output:

```
['GOUDA', 'Cappele aan de Ijsel', 'MAASBRACHT', 'MAASBRACHT', 'Laag Zuthm', 'Andelst-Jon Verkade_Nederland']
```